# How to convert path in javascript? especially with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, path

I have convert path 
from
`./modules/useraccounts/client/img/portfolio/uploads/98253cf4f19be659041f55552e5d973d` 
to

```
/modules/useraccounts/client/img/portfolio/uploads/98253cf4f19be659041f55552e5d973d
```

or from

```
modules\useraccounts\client\img\portfolio\uploads\98253cf4f19be659041f55552e5d973d
```

to

```
/modules/useraccounts/client/img/portfolio/uploads/98253cf4f19be659041f55552e5d973d
```

Should i have to make function from scratch?
I want to use powerful lib of javascript and angularjs.
And how to do it? 
Anything will be help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case just requires a [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
if (str[0] === '.') {
  str = str.slice(1);
}
```

The second case, I'd probably use a [`RegEx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str.replace(/\\/g, '/'); // the 'g' is for global; without it, only the first occurrence is replaced
```

These are both vanilla JavaScript methods. No need for any fancy Angular tricks here.

These two methods can be put into a simple function like so:

```
function formatPathString (str) {
  if (str[0] === '.') str = str.slice(1);
  return str.replace(/\\/g, '/');
}
```

One caveat: in a normal JS string, backslashes are used to escape/form special characters, so a path with backslashes may prove problematic if the backslashes are not accurately escaped.

In other words `"this\is\a\test".replace(/\\/g, '/')` will not result in `"this/is/a/test"`, but rather `"thisisa\test"` because the `\t` combination is meaningful, but the others aren't. You need to make sure any incoming strings with backslashes are properly escaped, as in: `"this\\is\\a\\test"` so that the `replace` method works as expected.

Comment: Thanks you.It's was big help for me